# .cshtml files displaying as plain html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having a problem setting up a website hosted on Windows Server 2012. The website is just the default website you get when setting up a new "ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2)" site. Then I simply published it using the "Publish Web Site" option in VS2012. I have also added the .cshtml extension in the MIME types. The server is running IIS v8 and .NET v4. The problem is when I visit the website this is how it displays:

http://i806.photobucket.com/albums/yy341/SamuelCB/Razor%20Error/Untitled.png
[image]

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do you even need to add the .cshtml MIME type?

Comment: What URL did you use in your browser to see that page?

Comment: @RowanFreeman I tried it without at first and I get the following error:


HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: It sounds like the web server isn't properly configured to handle what you're asking of it. Does the web server host other applications? Does it host other ASP.NET and/or MVC applications? What .NET framework? What IIS version? Try editing your question to be very thorough; what you've done, the steps you took, information about your server.

Comment: @RowanFreeman I have edited the question to include the IIS version and .NET framework version. As it says, it is IIS 8 and .NET v4. This is all running from a new setup of Windows Server 2012. The website can host other ASP.NET websites fine but not MVC4 using the Razor engine.

Comment: This looks to me like IIS isn't set up correctly. What .NET version is the Application Pool set to run as?

Comment: @RowanFreeman This is also set to run at .NET v4

Comment: Can we see the code of this .cshtml page please? Does this happen to every .cshtml page? Does it do this locally?

Comment: The code is just the default template. It is just basic HTML mixed with a few bits of razor code such as "@Page.Title" (You can also see the razor code in the post image as it is printing in plain text). This does happen to every .cshtml page. The application also does run locally.

Comment: If you dont mind blasting all sites on the box with a fresh install of .net for iis, run: aspnet_regiis -i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items to check:

- rarely do MIME Types actually matter if IIS **and** ASP.Net are installed properly

  - don't mis-interpret this statement, I'm not saying MIME types don't matter, just that if/when configured properly all of this, IIS/ASP.Net is "out of the box" without mucking with MIME types.
  - The issue with adding ".cshtml" manually is that IIS will (now) serve it, but the ASP.Net engine isn't (necessarily "there" for) handling it (e.g. integrated mode). That's why you're seeing the "unparsed" (raw) version of the file...code and all...it's all IIS (no ASP.net engine is configured to handle it).
- if you run your own box, run [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) - and it should give you insight on what's installed vs. what's not. Pay attention to ASP.Net bits and versions. You *may* need to [(re)register ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx)
- if you're hosted, just because your host has **.Net Framework 4.x** installed, *doesn't* mean they have all the bits and pieces of **ASP.Net** installed as well. *Ask your host for guidance* instead of doing a guessing game. I often have to "load" things that my dev machine has "by default" (of course its my machine) because I end up with non-functioning stuff when deployed to my host. You're not even getting an ASP.Net engine error, so that's a sure sign ASP.Net needs some work.

  - `Nuget` is excellent for this task. Some items that might be necessary to be "bin deployed" (aka. *you have to add them to your deployment/upload to `/bin` directory on your host*):

    - Microsoft ASP.NET Razor
    - Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages
    - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Unrelated: This sounds more like it should go to [`ServerFault`](https://serverfault.com/) rather than here on SO...I don't mind...but the community may think differently...and you might even get better answers....

Hth...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I installed Web Platform Installer, installed "IIS: ASP.NET 4.5", and then changed the application pool to .NET v4.5 in the IIS manager. Thanks again!