# Is it possible to access the server-side code in ASP.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i would like to know if it possible to access the server side code of a ASP.net website. Any application that can download the server side code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Kevin, your question is not clear. can you please, let me know what exactly you want's to do.

Comment: Are _you_ trying to download code or trying to keep _someone else_ from downloading code?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I need to implement an Ariba punchout system on our nopcommerce (MVC4). I thought maybe it be possible to download the code of a website who has done it and reverse-engineer it for our website, but it seems I cannot access it. Any idea?

Comment: Hi D Stanley, i wanted to download the code and analyze it, but i guess it is not possible.

Comment: @KevinNoori even if you _could_ it would be unethical, maybe even illegal.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you are trying to look into the your website code right? if yes then if it is publish then not possible. or you can refer the nopcommerce website. you can download the nop commerce code from codeplex

Comment: @Rahul Kumar hi rahul i was trying to look into the code of someone else in order to learn the development mechanism. I am trying to develop Ariba punchout for nopcommerce, but I am familiar with nopcommerce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a browser?  Probably not.  If the site is compiled then the code is build into a managed DLL.  Even if it's NOT compiled, then by default, IIS does not serve up .CS or .CONFIG files.  So you'll need direct access to the server in order to obtain the code-behind.

It's possible to *open up* holes that *would* allow code download, but by default downloading code directly should be very difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot.** The client only gets to see what is generated through server side code. You can't download server side code. If it was possible it would have caused serious security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above should cover the question. This is an "outlier":

- Not possible as stated above given a *correctly configured IIS box*
- BUT, for misconfigured IIS boxes, e.g. ASP.NET not installed, not mapped, etc., thereby meaning that an `aspx` or `cshtml/vbhtml` file is treated as, well, text, then yes, it's possible.

As stated this is an outlier. However, you will see questions on [SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19918255/304683), so it's not "impossible".

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not possible in a systematic way.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the application itself provides the facility to download its code then it can...Otherwise on browser what you get is the html and client script that the application allowed to render...